# Nested if-else statements not returning correct value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to print whether or not a column value is contained in an excel file.

At first, I used an if statement, then two elifs, and finally, an else. I then changed the elifs to if-else statements because I thought that was the issue, but I still get the incorrect value.

```
if 'Strip Circuit ID' in ws.columns:
    print('Contains Strip Circuit ID')
    #col6
    cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=6)
    print(cell.value)
else:
    if 'STRIP_EC_CIRCUIT_ID' in ws.columns:
        print('Contains STRIP_EC_CIRCUIT_ID')
        #col9
        cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=9)
        print(cell.value)
    else:
        if 'Circuit ID' in ws.columns:
            print('Contains Circuit ID')
            #col6
            cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=6)
            print(cell.value)
        else:
            print('NONE')
```

I expect that when the file has 'Strip Circuit ID', 'STRIP_EC_CIRCUIT_ID', or 'Circuit ID', that it will return the value within the if-else statements, but the program is just returning 'NONE'.

Comment: use `print(ws.columns)` to check what you have in this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ws.columns` returns a generator of columns, each containing cells so the check doesn't make any sense. You must check the value of every cell in every column.

```
for col in ws.columns:
    for cell in col:
        if "Circuit ID" in cell.value:
            print(cell.coordinate)
```